# MQTT on React Native?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native, mqtt

I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to go when adding MQTT to a react-native project I have.  The project needs to run on iOS and Android, so ideally the MQTT can be handled in the javascript side.  I realize the networking lair is different from mobile to classic node, so I began down the route of forking MQTT.js and have hit roadblock after roadblock.

Should I continue down the route of forking MQTT.js? Should I aim to replicate the node environment on the mobile environment with polyfills or some other means?  Should I break down and get an objective C library and a Java library and wrap them?

Comment: I guess my biggest concern is, should we use a js solution or a native module solution for mqtt?
Do JS solutions flood the react-native bridge and make our app slower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had moderate success using [react-native-mqtt](https://github.com/tuanpmt/react-native-mqtt) both on Android and iOS. It simply bridges over native modules per each platform, Paho on Android and [MQTTClient](https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework) on iOS.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to use https://github.com/rusfearuth/react-native-mqtt, because of original library use deprecated API and has bugs in native code and it isn't production ready )

Comment: @Rusfearuth , is managed to install and run your library, but i get following errors continuously: 
 'mqtt.event.error', 'Connection to lost! Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException' 
Then it connects and disconnects again and this is happening every second or so. Probably due to it not being maintained, library isn't prod ready anymore?

Comment: Issue was with my client_id, could do my tests by using empty client_id.
But main question still valid, what is the most maintained fork of this library nowadays?

Answer (score 8):

I did some research and it looks like the way to go is with native (tcp) mqtt, and not mqtt over websockets (eventhough you could do both).

The road was unpaved, so after looking into all of our options, I ended up  modifying tuanpmt/react-native-mqtt in order to make the library more stable, and are now using it in production.

There you go: https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-mqtt

That's native mqtt (using iOS and Android mqtt libraries) and not a websockets js library that needs weird configuration and imports to work with react-native. I'd say that's your best bet right now.

`npm install sp-react-native-mqtt` and then follow the steps in readme to use it.

Try it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as all other library are deprecated or are using websocket to connect to broker. I lost 1 day searching and understanding why all other library weren't working.

Comment: what are possible values for  qos in subscribe(topic, qos) function.

Answer (score 6):

After really needing the [react-native-mqtt](https://github.com/tuanpmt/react-native-mqtt) to work and failing to configure it properly, alas, I have found [react_native_mqtt](https://github.com/Introvertuous/react_native_mqtt). Yes, they look the same but trust me, they're different.

In this module you won't have to struggle with Podfiles (ios) or MainActivity.java or MainApplication.java (android) files to get this working. All you will need to do is include it.

and follow the [instructions](https://github.com/Introvertuous/react_native_mqtt):

```
import { initMqtt } from 'react_native_mqtt';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

... your awesome code below!
```