# Which WebSocket-based libraries work with React Native?

Tags: node.js, websocket, react-native

Based on my research and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753636/mqtt-on-react-native/35754055) it seems that some WebSocket based Nodejs libraries do not work with React Native (e.g. Paho's JS library for MQTT), but others do work (e.g. [SocketIO](http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/05/16/react-native-and-socket-dot-io/) and [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-20-tutorial-firebase-react-native.html)).

Is there any way to know other than trial and error which ones are likely to work?

### Summary:

Sounds like most WebSocket based libraries should work and that inconsistencies with the way React Native implements XMLHttpRequest is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use 'ws' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) server-side. It works fine. React-native supports client-side WebSocket (both android and ios) but with some lacks (f.e. it doesn't support cookies yet).

Comment: Do you know why Paho's JS doesn't work? I'm not using nodejs on the backend so do you know if another language agnostic protocol such as STOMP is supported?

Comment: Didn't try Paho's JS. I think a lot of protocols should work on top of react-native XMLHttpRequest (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#xmlhttprequest) but I had no chances to check.

Comment: That's the issue - I've read that there are inconsistencies with the react-native XMLHttpRequest implementation but I can't find any summary other than this mess https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Not working on me :( When I require ws module, it saids: Requiring unknown module "url". I reinstall the modules but not worked either.

Answer (score 1):

React native supports websockets. You can find detailed information at the link.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: Not so detailed unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

We're using SignalR in a React Native iOS project and it's working really well. 
https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr

It's an interesting implementation - it uses the browser version of the SignalR client (which requires JQuery) and shims only the (very few) parts of the JQuery library that it actually uses so it can work under React Native.